# space.pies not adding pie charts to marmap in r

Tags: r, charts, maps, pie-chart

I am trying to add pie charts to a map in marmap. I was able to create the map I want using:

```
dat <- getNOAA.bathy(14,24,57,61,res=4, keep=TRUE)
autoplot(dat, geom=c("r", "c"), colour="white", size=0.1) + scale_fill_etopo()
```

But when I try to add data points or pie charts nothing comes up or I get the error: 
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state

I think I followed the example in space.pies correctly so I'm not sure where I went wrong. I have tried clearing my workspace and re-running the code and it hasn't helped. Below is the code I have tried. I am trying to create 7 pie charts, each with 8 possible slices, so I specified the frequency of each slice (freq.a through freq.h) and the colors of each slice (col.a through col.h). Then I specified my coordinates (x and y). Then I create the data frame for the points, call up the map, add the points and the pie charts.

```
freq.a<-c(0, 0, 0, 0.657894737, 0, 0.555555556, 0)
freq.b<-c(0,0.847457627,0,0,0,0.555555556,0)
freq.c<-c(8.333333333,10.16949153,15,10.52631579,6.666666667,14.44444444,12.63736264)
freq.d<-c(75.83333333,68.6440678,70.83333333,71.71052632,73.33333333,66.11111111,71.97802198)
freq.e<-c(0,0,0,0,1.666666667,0,0.549450549)
freq.f<-c(10,17.79661017,8.333333333,13.15789474,15,13.88888889,12.08791209)
freq.g<-c(5.833333333,2.542372881,5.833333333,3.947368421,3.333333333,3.888888889,2.747252747)
freq.h<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0.555555556,0)
col.a<-rep("red",7)
col.b<-rep("orange",7)
col.c<-rep("yellow",7)
col.d<-rep("green",7)
col.e<-rep("blue",7)
col.f<-rep("purple",7)
col.g<-rep("black",7)
col.h<-rep("white",7)


y=c(58.78627075,59.625881,59.06541145,58.029829,60.33012651,58.69069925,58.29392997)    
x=c(17.5868715,18.9053088,18.28217463,16.753265,18.47761255,17.17527965,16.92259188)

pts=data.frame(x,y,freq.a, freq.b, freq.c, freq.d, freq.e, freq.f, freq.g, freq.h, col.a, col.b, col.c, col.d, col.e, col.f, col.g, col.h)

dat <- getNOAA.bathy(14,24,57,61,res=4, keep=TRUE)
autoplot(dat, geom=c("r", "c"), colour="white", size=0.1) + scale_fill_etopo()
points(pts,pch=19,col="blue", cex=0.5)
space.pies(pts[,1],  pts[,2],
       pie.slices=pts[,3:10], pie.colors=pts[,11:18], pie.radius=0.5)
```

Comment: I'm afraid `space.pies()` is not designed to work with bathymetry maps produced with `ggplot2`. Since you used `autoplot()` to produce the bathymetry, an error is returned. I agree the help file should be more explicit about that... If you use `plot.bathy()` instead, you should be fine.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, I was able to make it work using plot.bathy(). I also noticed that zeros are skipped when creating the pie graphs, so it messes up the color scheme. I ended up replacing the zeros in my data with 0.001 just to keep the color scheme in order.